# HTML5 Cross-domain XmlHttpRequest vs. Older XmlHttpRequests

Tags: javascript, xml, html, xmlhttprequest

I've sensed a lot of ramble about easy cross-domain XmlHttpRequest methods with new HTML5 JS XHR techniques.  Given the standard JavaScript XHR code below...

```
  var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET",url,false);
  xhr.send();
  var output=xhr.responseXML;
```

...what would be the equivalent HTML5 XHR cross-domain-enabled code that would give the same output?

Comment: @fmsf, `jsonp` is not HTML5 specific.

Comment: I think you are thinking of [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), which has nothing to do with HTML 5.

Comment: Yes, I was familiar with CORS, just a little confused about the other stuff...  Got it clear now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing different from the JS perspective.  The cross-domain authorization is handled by the browser on the HTTP level using [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control), so your server has to support cross-domain negotiation.

Comment: So this happens only if your doctype is set to HTML5 or in all sitations so long as the browser supports HTML5?

Comment: @wagtail, CORS has nothing to do with HTML5. It's been around for long time. So it doesn't really matter what DOCTYPE you've used. What matters is if the client browser supports it and whether the server sends the correct HTTP response headers. So, no, HTML5 doesn't bring anything new to cross domain javascript screen scrapers. They are still as PITA as they are currently :-)

Comment: @josh3736 What if the website you are trying to access hasn't indicated Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ?

Comment: @wagtail, in this case it doesn't work. You forget about cross domain AJAX.

Comment: Then you can't do it.  The point of CORS is that the *server* has to say it's OK for you to make a cross-domain request.

Comment: I see.  Understood much better!  Thanks.